# How to link to dynamic boost libs?

Tags: c++, boost

I compiled boost lib and got these.

```
//Shared/dynamic link libraries

24/03/2010  11:25 PM            53,248 boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.dll
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,054 boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,054 boost_thread-vc80-mt.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM            73,728 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.dll
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,214 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,214 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd.lib

// Static libs... does not need any dlls

24/03/2010  11:25 PM           381,716 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           381,716 libboost_thread-vc80-mt.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM           999,552 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           999,552 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM           421,050 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-s-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           421,050 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-s.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM         1,015,688 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM         1,015,688 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd.lib
```

In Visual Studio, I have written a test app using the boost thread library. Based on code generation settings it asks for these four libs only (like multithreading debug, multithreading, multithreading debug dll, and multithreading  dll)

```
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           381,716 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           381,716 libboost_thread-vc80-mt.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM           999,552 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           999,552 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-gd.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM           421,050 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-s-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM           421,050 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-s.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM         1,015,688 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM         1,015,688 libboost_thread-vc80-mt-sgd.lib
```

Now my question is how can I link my app to the other 2 libs so that it uses the dlls?

```
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            53,248 boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.dll
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,054 boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,054 boost_thread-vc80-mt.lib

24/03/2010  11:25 PM            73,728 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.dll
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,214 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd-1_42.lib
24/03/2010  11:25 PM            17,214 boost_thread-vc80-mt-gd.lib
```

Question 2. What does the g, s stands for?

Answer (score 38):

You can force Boost to use the DLLs by defining `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` - either in your C++ preprocessor settings or by a `#define` in your `stdafx.h` pre-compiled header, e.g.:

`#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`

Answer (score 22):

To configure boost use the user config header

```
<boost/config/user.hpp>
```

Then just look for the dynamic link lines and change to your desired configuration

```
// BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK: Forces all libraries that have separate source, 
// to be linked as DLL's rather than static libraries on Microsoft Windows 
// (this macro is used to turn on __declspec(dllimport) modifiers, so that 
// the compiler knows which symbols to look for in a DLL rather than in a 
// static library).  Note that there may be some libraries that can only 
// be statically linked (Boost.Test for example) and others which may only 
// be dynamically linked (Boost.Threads for example), in these cases this 
// macro has no effect.
// #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

Answer (score 13):

1. The .lib files are linked statically, while .dll files are linked dynamically. I believe it's a VC project setting.
2. 

```
The "lib" prefix is for static libraries. Use link=static 
The 's' letter is to static linking to runtime. Use runtime-link=static 
The 'd' is debug, use variant=debug 
The 'g' is using debug runtime, I think it's included in 'debug' variant 
already. If not runtime-debugging=on will help.
```

Source: http://old.nabble.com/Build-statically-linked-boost-libs-*-vc90-mt-sgd.lib-td16301103.html

Comment: Better source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming

Comment: even better source https://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

Comment: Updated link: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming