# Using boost library's dll version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, boost

I followed the start-up guide in boost library and was able to use the library in a static-linked form, i.e., use .lib version of library files. I did this just by adding the path to the library to Additional Library Directories in Visual Studio 2010.

I am wondering how I can use the DLL version of the library. In Visual Studio, everything seems quite automated. Is there any simple configuration allows me to do that? Or do I need to change my code? Maybe add some macro?

Thanks

Comment: Does Boost even *have* DLL versions of its libraries? It has versions that link with the standard libraries via DLL, but that's rather different from Boost *itself* being a DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First google result [How to link to dynamic boost libs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs)

Put in stdafx.h or as a project settings define:

```
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```