# Linking to Boost libraries fails because of lib prefix

Tags: boost, linker

I installed boost v1.47 DLL (MT, Debug) for VC9 from boostpro. My code `#include`'s `<boost/regex.hpp>`. When I try to build, VC gives me `LNK1104 cannot open file libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_47.lib`, even though `boost_1_47/lib` has been added to **Additional Library Dependencies** (in double quotes). The problem seems to be that the name of the library in the directory is not `libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_47.lib`, but simply `boost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_47.lib`.

How do I get VC to omit the leading 'lib' ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

In Boost the lib prefix denotes whether the libraries were built for static or dynamic (shared) linking. To indicate you want to dynamically link the libraries (as the name without the lib prefix implies) define the preprocessor directive of `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`.

In Visual Studio, go to the project's settings, and select **Configuration Properties** > **C/C++** > **Preprocessor** page.  Add `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` to **Preprocessor Definitions**.

See also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521866/483776