# Use compiled Boost library with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, compilation

I try to use compiled Boost library (FileSystem) with Visual Studio.
So, I add the boost lib directory in :

Project Properties > Linker > Additional Library Directories

The problem is Visual Studio try to add a prefix lib :

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib'
```

But the real name of the lib is simply boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib

How to disable the prefix before the lib name ?

Thank you !

Comment: `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib` is a static library. `boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib` is an import library for a dll. You can find [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) the naming convention used by boost. You can either use shared linking in your project or rebuild boost using `link=static` if you must use static linking.

Comment: I saw this page but how to fix my problem ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2521866/1252091) should work.

Comment: I didn't compile Boost, I used BoostPro. Any idea how to do with BoostPro ? Thx

Comment: As it was said in the link in my second comment, you just need to add `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` before you include any boost header. You can put it for example in your stdafx.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a problem of a prefix. To fix that I just launched the BoostPro installer and installed all the debug lib.