# Boost lib and not-lib .lib files

Tags: boost, compilation

Why, when compiling Boost, don't I have the `lib<name>.lib` files, and instead have `<name>.lib` files?

For example: as compilation result, I have obtained the `boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_56.lib`file but not the `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_56.lib` file.

Comment: looks like you have `<name>.lib` for dynamically-linked library, look for corresponding .dll (.so?) somewhere in `bin` folder. to have statically-linked library you need to configure Boost build, check available command-line parameters

Comment: Sorry, I did't understand you answer; I have run the following command in order to compile, and I have obtained also the .dll files (e.g. boost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_56.dll, i.e. still w/out "lib" at the beginning of the name) in the _install\lib under the boost root dir : b2.exe -j 8 -a --toolset=msvc --without-mpi --without-python --prefix=_install --build-dir=./build address-model=64 variant=debug,release link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared install

Comment: I have found now this other post, that seems having all the answers to my doubts :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380597/use-compiled-boost-library-with-visual-studio-2010?rq=1 Tnx anyway!

Comment: Ok solution is to use the dynamic version of the libs, and in order to understand how to do this, the solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs/2521866#2521866 Txn everybody