# linking error: ambiguous libboost*.lib vs boost*.lib

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost in my project. I've downloaded pre-compiled binaries from here http://boost.teeks99.com/

When linking I receive such error:

`Error  18  error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl boost::thread::join(void)" (?join@thread@boost@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib(boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.dll) C:\Oleg\projects\MBClient\FastNativeAdapter\libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib(thread.obj)   FastNativeAdapter`

Why boost contains two `lib` with so similar name, what is the difference between them?

- libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib
- boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib

How to fix linking error?

**upd** I've compiled boost myself. I've added `boost_1_53_0\stage\lib` directory to linker. This directory actually contains 3 "copies" of "each" file, for example:

- boost_atomic-vc110-mt-1_53.dll
- boost_atomic-vc110-mt-1_53.lib
- libboost_atomic-vc110-mt-1_53.lib

So It's clear what compiler claims about. Somehow it can't understand which version of lib file to use. It's likely connected with static/dinamic linking, but I still can not find the solution. I'm sure my problems is pretty common so I hope someone can suggest me what to do.

I've tried to delete all "libboost*" files from folder but then I receive such error:
`Error  15  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_53.lib'`

I've tried to delete all "boost*lib" files from folder but then I receive such error:
`Error  15  error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib'`

Then I copied `boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib` back and I receive a lot of errors like that:

`Error  16  error LNK2005: "public: virtual __cdecl boost::detail::thread_data_base::~thread_data_base(void)" (??1thread_data_base@detail@boost@@UEAA@XZ) already defined in boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib(boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.dll)`

So when there are no `boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib` compiler claims that it's missing, when there is `boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_53.lib` compiler claims that "function is already defined". Probaly somehow I do use dinamic and static linking at the same time or something like that?

**upd2** i've uncommented `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs/3051417#3051417) and now code compiles! i'm investigating if everything else is fine. however i didn't understand why I should uncomment `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` so comments are welcome.

Comment: You attempt to link both static and dynamic versions of Boost.Thread. `boost_thread` is the import library for dll, `libboost_thread` is static library.

Comment: why VS linking both, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Usually VS doesn't do this, so the question is what's wrong with your settings. Do you have `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` defined? Do you link with CRT statically or dynamically (/MT or /MD)? Do you force linking some of the above libs (Linker-->Input-->Aditional dependencies or `# pragma comment(lib,...)`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asking myquestion myself.
need to uncomment #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK (refer to description)

Answer (score 7):

Edit: Initial statement removed since an edit to the post changed the situation.

Based on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming (as provided by Igor R.):

libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib is a static lib (no need for the DLL)
boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib is the import lib for the DLL

You only need to use one of these.

Comment: Prior to the edit, one was listed as a dll. Please post the sizes of the two; if one is much smaller than the other then the large one is likely a static library, removing the need for the dll. If they're closer, one may be a debug version while the other is release.

Comment: @mah please read about boost naming conventions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming

Comment: @IgorR. that page seems to just solidify my last comment, no? It seems to me from the link you provided that libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib will be much larger as it will be the normal static lib, while boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib will be the import library used to pull in the DLL. If this is true, I think my first comment was sufficient, no?

Comment: @mah My point was that it's worth reading the manual, instead of trying to guess -- especially when there're real unknowns in the problem (like why VS attempts to link both static and import libs).

Answer (score 1):

Another idea/solution to try if you hit the `error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-*.lib'` error:

In our project, we include the `boost/date_time.hpp` file. We define the constant  `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` instead of BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in our project settings to tell boost not to automatically select which libraries to link against.
See the Boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html#boost_config.configuring_boost_for_your_platform.user_settable_options) for more information about this option.

So you could add `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions and check whether this linker error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you need to correct your question. Do you mean (I guess you already know the difference between `DLL` and `LIB` )

- libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib
- boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.**dll**

or

- libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib
- boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.**lib**

Anyway, it seems the issue is you're mixing static(`libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib`) and shared (`boost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib`) boost libraries. But without the working environment and platform details I cannot purpose an exact solution. If you work in `Visual Studio` ,then you can go to `right click on project file` > `properties` > `linker` > `input` > `ignore specific library` and add `libboost_thread-vc110-mt-1_52.lib` there and try.

Comment: thanks i'm trying to build boost from scratch probably my version become broken by some reason...