# Using Boost.asio in Visual C++ Forms project with dynamic link libraries and using #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK still same errors

Tags: c++, winforms, boost, boost-asio

I'm using visual studio 2010 I built boost using

```
b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete --libdir=C:\Boost\lib\i386 install
```

And I'm trying to run a lan file sharing client console application that works perfectly from a c++ forms applications. So i added

```
#include <boost/config/user.hpp>
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

to stdafx.h arcording to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs)! 
but i get the same errors.

```
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(213): warning C4272: 'boost::system::system_category' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(214): warning C4272: 'boost::system::generic_category' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(399): warning C4394: 'boost::system::throws' : per-appdomain symbol should not be marked with __declspec(dllimport)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(52): error C2664: 'QueueUserAPC' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__stdcall *)(ULONG_PTR)' to 'PAPCFUNC'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(82): error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_thread.hpp(31): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::win_thread_function' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_thread.hpp(36): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::apc_function' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(43): error C3862: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::win_fenced_block': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>          Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(43): error C3645: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::win_fenced_block' : __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(63): error C3862: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::~win_fenced_block': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>          Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(63): error C3645: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::~win_fenced_block' : __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp(99): warning C4164: '_InterlockedExchange' : intrinsic function not declared
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp(100): warning C4164: '_InterlockedExchangeAdd' : intrinsic function not declared
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_w32.hpp(62): error C3861: '_InterlockedExchange': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(44): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(48): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_number' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(49): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(50): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(52): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_short_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(53): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_long_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(55): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_enum' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::~greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(61): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(64): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(66): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::operator unsigned short' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(68): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_number' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(69): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_enum' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(70): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(71): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(73): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(74): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(77): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(82): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(86): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(91): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(95): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::~greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp(158): warning C4272: 'boost::date_time::nth_as_str' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(74): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(74): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(257): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(257): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(327): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(327): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(381): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(381): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_object_handle_service.hpp(157): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::wait_callback' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>client.cpp(71): warning C4129: 'l' : unrecognized character escape sequence
1>client.cpp(72): warning C4129: 'l' : unrecognized character escape sequence
1>  test1.cpp
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(213): warning C4272: 'boost::system::system_category' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(214): warning C4272: 'boost::system::generic_category' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/system/error_code.hpp(399): warning C4394: 'boost::system::throws' : per-appdomain symbol should not be marked with __declspec(dllimport)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(52): error C2664: 'QueueUserAPC' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__stdcall *)(ULONG_PTR)' to 'PAPCFUNC'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/win_thread.ipp(82): error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_thread.hpp(31): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::win_thread_function' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_thread.hpp(36): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::apc_function' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(43): error C3862: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::win_fenced_block': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>          Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(43): error C3645: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::win_fenced_block' : __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(63): error C3862: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::~win_fenced_block': cannot compile an unmanaged function with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>          Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_fenced_block.hpp(63): error C3645: 'boost::asio::detail::win_fenced_block::~win_fenced_block' : __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp(99): warning C4164: '_InterlockedExchange' : intrinsic function not declared
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/detail/interlocked.hpp(100): warning C4164: '_InterlockedExchangeAdd' : intrinsic function not declared
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/smart_ptr/detail/spinlock_w32.hpp(62): error C3861: '_InterlockedExchange': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(44): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(48): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_number' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(49): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(50): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(52): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_short_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(53): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_long_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(55): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::as_enum' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::~greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::greg_weekday' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_weekday.hpp(58): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_weekday::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(61): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(64): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(66): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::operator unsigned short' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(68): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_number' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(69): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_enum' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(70): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(71): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(73): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(74): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_wstring' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(77): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(82): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(86): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(91): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(95): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::~greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::greg_month' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/gregorian/greg_month.hpp(99): warning C4272: 'boost::gregorian::greg_month::operator =' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/date_time/date_generators.hpp(158): warning C4272: 'boost::date_time::nth_as_str' : is marked __declspec(dllimport); must specify native calling convention when importing a function.
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(74): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(74): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(257): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(257): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(327): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(327): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(381): error C2039: 'signal' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/impl/signal_set_service.ipp(381): error C3861: 'signal': identifier not found
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/endpoint.hpp(27): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/detail/impl/endpoint.ipp(32): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/basic_endpoint.hpp(25): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/datagram_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/raw_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/seq_packet_protocol.hpp(30): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2059: syntax error : 'generic'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/generic/stream_protocol.hpp(31): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost/asio/detail/win_object_handle_service.hpp(157): error C3641: 'boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::wait_callback' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>c:\users\pop\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test1\test1\client.cpp(71): warning C4129: 'l' : unrecognized character escape sequence
1>c:\users\pop\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test1\test1\client.cpp(72): warning C4129: 'l' : unrecognized character escape sequence
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the library with C++/CLI? None of the error messages suggest you have a linker problem (which is where the BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK comes in) but they all point at code that won't really compile with C++/CLI. If that's the case you might want to forego C++/CLI for the piece of code that needs ASIO.

Comment: so i have to rewrite my console applications in C++/CLI? Isn't there any other workaround?

Comment: No, what I was asking is if you *are* compiling the code as C++/CLI. The warnings complain about you compiling the code with /clr. A lot of boost libraries only compile with straight, native C++.

Comment: It seems that I'm compiling the code with CLR. What should I do?