# Boost::asio linking; identifier not found; C++

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-asio

I googled the error lines of my problem and got hardly any hits and I don't speak russian.  I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17758543/using-boost-asio-in-visual-c-forms-project-with-dynamic-link-libraries-and-usi), but it doesn't seem to help me.

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main() {

    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io,boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    t.wait();
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

These be my error messages:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\sdk\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_thread.ipp(52): error C2039: 'QueueUserAPC' : is not a member of '`global namespace''
1>c:\sdk\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_thread.ipp(52): error C3861: 'QueueUserAPC': identifier not found
1>c:\sdk\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp(374): error C3861: 'RegisterWaitForSingleObject': identifier not found
1>c:\sdk\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp(416): error C3861: 'RegisterWaitForSingleObject': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any insights would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**
Adding `#include <Windows.h>` before the headers changed the error messages to

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\prsht.h(607): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hdr'
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\prsht.h(607): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\windows.h(247): warning C4193: #pragma warning(pop) : no matching '#pragma warning(push)'
1>c:\sdk\boost\asio\detail\socket_types.hpp(22): fatal error C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included
```

prsht.h:
tracking that down lead me to find this:

```
typedef struct _PSHNOTIFY
{
    NMHDR hdr; //line 607 NMHDR is undefined.  
    LPARAM lParam;
} PSHNOTIFY, *LPPSHNOTIFY;
```

Not real sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try including `Windows.h` before boost asio header.

Comment: it looks like you're missing some windows headers, which is weird: I would assume that the boost headers would automatically include them, if they do use the API. Perhaps you need to check your project configuration?

Comment: Yeah, something odd is going on.  Well this is the first sdk I've used that didn't have me add some .lib to the dependancies and add .dll files to the project folder.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: well I found [this][1] the solution is there in the last comment but I don't understand it.


[1]:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/be7b5c16-ce4e-4682-b276-4e9fb7087092/regsearch-sample-build-error

Comment: Did you download and configure boost?  It looks like you may be using headers that are set for a different compiler.  Follow the instructions on how to build boost for your specific compiler (start here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html )

Comment: The solution is to *delete* the whole Boost tree, download & unzip a fresh non-corrupted Boost archive, and try again.

Comment: @Guy Sirton 
Did I download, certainly, otherwise it wouldn't be able to find the header.  Did I configure?  Please explain what you mean.  Boost is mostly header only libraries, there is no .dll or lib to link.  I have added the boost directly to my #include directories via the project properties dialog in vs 2012.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Chemistpp: Some Boost libraries do have binaries you need to build.  Asio used to require a binary library but I think it optional now, read the asio docs.  Regardless, if you follow the link I provided precisely you should be able to go from zero to a compiling program.  You shouldn't need to modify any compiler headers or perform any other magic.

Comment: @Guy that is what I am getting at.  I didn't 'follow it' when I set it up, but after you posted it, I verified it three times over.  I have even repeated the process from scratch.

Comment: @Igor R.  zip file SHA1 and MD5 hash matches the specified values.

Comment: @Guy Sirton Asio always was header-only. It depends on Boost.System though, which should be built. But all this is irrelevant to the OP issue.

Comment: @GuySirton Yes, you seem to be right.  I played around with some of the project settings.  I added #include path to the vC++ directors as well as under the C/C++ Generals tab.  Now it's asking for the blah.system.lib which indeed is one of the libraries that require building.

Comment: @IgorR. Yes, my Boost.System is missing! Thanks both of you.

Comment: @IgorR. There's an option for binaries (see under "Optional separate compilation") and that's relatively new IIRC.

Comment: Verified.  Not exactly sure the initial problem that gave `error C2039: 'QueueUserAPC' : is not a member of '`global namespace''`.  Maybe VC++ directory include setting isn't enough.  Specifically add it to the C/C++ general setting for #include directories.  Then, the error of missing the .lib file was solved by following standard boost build instructions as provided in Guy Sirton's comment.  This was necessary because boost::asio is dependent upon the boost::system library which needs to be built.

Comment: @Guy Sirton right, but even this new feature doesn't provide a "separate build" in terms of Boost (you still can't pre-build Asio binary with bjam). It's merely a macro that allows to include Asio source-files into your own project.