# Linking boost with PCL using MS Build Tools and command line

Tags: c++, boost, point-cloud-library

I'm using PLC 1.11 installed from the allinone-msvc2019-win64.exe installer. I'm doing a command-line build using MS Build Tools and NMake. The code I'm testing the build with [is the example](https://pcl-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_pcd.html) from "Writing Point Cloud data to PCD files" tutorial. I can compile the resulting source to an object file just fine:

```
cl /c /Zi /EHsc /MTd /Fe.\intermediate\x86\pcd_write.obj /I"\Program Files\PCL 1.11.0\include\pcl-1.11"  /I"\Program Files\PCL 1.11.0\3rdParty\Eigen\eigen3"  /I"\Program Files\PCL 1.11.0\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost-1_73" .\src\pcd_write.cpp
```

But when linking, it tries to link to the wrong ABI tag for the boost library:

```
link /LIBPATH:"\Program Files\PCL 1.11.0\lib"  /LIBPATH:"\Program Files\PCL 1.11.0\3rdParty\Boost\lib"  /LIBPATH:"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\lib\x64" /out:.\bin\x86\pcd_write.exe .\intermediate\x86\pcd_write.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.26.28806.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-sgd-x64-1_73.lib'
```

Note that it should be libbost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_73.lib. No "s". I'm assuming that I have a link argument wrong (or possibly a compiler argument wrong). But I can't weed through to figure out what. How do I tell the compiler/linker which Boost library to link to?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715164/how-can-i-decode-the-boost-library-naming)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520234/how-to-link-to-dynamic-boost-libs)